# Add Product to Cart via SOAP error - Please specify the product required option(s)

Tags: magento-1.7, api, custom-options, soap

I am trying to use the [shoppingCartProductAdd](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html) SOAP API to add a product with Custom Options to cart.

Below is the array I am passing for the products parameter. I've a required custom option id 1 for which the selected value id in the dropdown is 2. (you can view the [product here](http://hominova.webly.co/apple-macbook-pro-ma464ll-a-15-4-notebook-pc-2-0-ghz-intel-core-duo-1-gb-ram-100-gb-hard-drive-superdrive.html))

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'product_id' => int 25
      'qty' => int 1
      'options' => 
        array (size=1)
          1 => int 2
```

When I execute this SOAP request, I get an error **"Please specify the product required option(s)."**

It looks like its not accepting my 'options' key in the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this problem by using the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899127/setting-custom-options-while-adding-a-product-to-cart-via-soap-in-magento/19925338#19925338

The format in which options needs to be passed as not as stated in the Magento SOAP documentation.

Comment: Good advice: Never trust the Magento SOAP documentation. Go and have a look in the code instead.